# How do I take the union of sets?

Tags: java, list, set, combinations, set-union

Is there any optimal way to get all union of `n` sets?

This is what I have done, but it is very slow for a large number of sets:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Set<Integer>>> unionSet = new ArrayList<>();
    List<List<Integer>> sets = ...
    double avail = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= sets.size(); i++) {
        List<Set<Integer>> us = new ArrayList<>();
        union(sets, us, new HashSet<>(), i, 0);
        unionSet.add(us);
    }
}
```

```java
public static void union(
        List<List<Integer>> sets, List<Set<Integer>> unionSet,
        Set<Integer> set, int size, int index) {
    for (int i = index; i < sets.size(); i++) {
        Set temp = new HashSet(set);
        temp.addAll(sets.get(i));

        if (size != 1)
            union(sets, unionSet, temp, size - 1, i + 1);
        else
            unionSet.add(temp);
    }
}
```

[The intersection of all combinations of `n` sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028124/the-intersection-of-all-combinations-of-n-sets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Stream#flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method as follows:

1. If you have a *list* of *sets*, you can *flatten* its elements (i.e. *sets*) into one *set* of unique values:

   ```java
   List<Set<Integer>> setList =
           List.of(Set.of(1, 2, 3), Set.of(2, 3, 7));

   Set<Integer> set = setList.stream()
           .flatMap(Set::stream)
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());

   System.out.println(set); // [1, 2, 3, 7]
   ```
2. If you have a *deeper* level of nesting, then you have to perform a *deeper flattening*:

   ```java
   List<List<Set<Integer>>> lists = List.of(
           List.of(Set.of(1, 2, 3), Set.of(2, 3, 4)),
           List.of(Set.of(3, 4, 5), Set.of(5, 1, 2)));

   Set<Integer> set = lists
           // Stream<List<Set<Integer>>>
           .stream()
           // Stream<Set<Integer>>
           .flatMap(List::stream)
           // Stream<Integer>
           .flatMap(Set::stream)
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());

   System.out.println(set); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   ```
3. If you have *several collections* with *unknown* level of nesting, you can create a *generic recursive flattening* method:

   ```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Set<Integer>> setList =
               List.of(Set.of(1, 2, 3), Set.of(2, 3, 7));

       List<List<Set<Integer>>> lists = List.of(
               List.of(Set.of(1, 2, 3), Set.of(2, 3, 4)),
               List.of(Set.of(3, 4, 5), Set.of(5, 1, 2)));

       Set<Integer> set = (Set<Integer>) toSet(setList, lists);
       System.out.println(set); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
   }
   ```

   ```java
   public static Set<?> toSet(Collection<?>... collections) {
       return Arrays.stream(collections)
               .flatMap(col -> flattenStream(col.stream()))
               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
   }
   ```

   ```java
   public static Stream<?> flattenStream(Stream<?> stream) {
       return stream.flatMap(e -> {
           if (e instanceof Collection) {
               return flattenStream(((Collection<?>) e).stream());
           } else {
               return Stream.of(e);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

---

<sup>See also:

• [Parallelized Matrix Multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66000825/14940971)

• [The intersection of all combinations of `n` sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66068023/14940971)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
Set s1 = Set.of(1,2,3);
Set s2 = Set.of(3,4,5);     
Set union = Stream.concat(s1.stream(),s2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or

```
s1.addAll(s2;
```

Go with the above-inbuilt java lib